How can I get Pandera to accept bool and boolean in a data frame column?
I am reading in a parquet file using awswrangler. Right after I read my data, I use Python's Pandera library to validate the DF. A boolean column with just 15 rows and no empty values fails the validation. The error I get is:
pandera.errors.SchemaError: expected series 'column_name' to have type bool, got boolean
If I explicitly set the column type to bool, the validation passes. I have no idea why Pandora makes the distinction between bool and boolean.
Example code that passes validation:
df = wr.s3.read_parquet(path=s3_path)
df["column_name"] = df["column_name"].astype(bool)
validate_df_against_schema(df, PanderaSchema)

Pandera schema definition for this column:
class PanderaSchema(pa.DataFrameModel):
    column_name: Series[bool] = pa.Field(nullable=True)

The following screenshot shows individual cell data and dtype of that cell. Top half is before I convert it to bool, the bottom is after the conversion. Python interprets both as bool. Yet to pander there seems to be a difference.
enter image description here
Why can't I get the validation to just pass without having to convert it to bool?
What adds to my confusion is that I validate the same data, with the same pandora schema, right before writing it to parquet with wrangler in the first place. As soon as I read it back, the validation fails on the boolean column.
How can I get Pandora work without the explicit boolean conversion?
I tried reading in the DF using wrangler with a pre-defined pyarrow schema:
import pyarrow as pyar

pyarrow_read_data_schema = pyar.schema(
    [("column_name", pyar.bool_())]
)

df = wr.s3.read_parquet(path=s3_path, schema=pyarrow_read_data_schema)

The same error persists.

Please do not post code as images, see here for the reason.
